# How to display the input values stored in Formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

My understanding at current point is using

```
import {connect} from 'formik';

const Some = connect(SomeRender);
```

then

```
const SomeRender = (props) => { props.formik.values } // should have data
```

but the `formik` is an empty object and will not get update from `formik`.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Actually what is the question here?

Comment: updated the title to make it clear